Can AES be used to perform encryption in the algorithm of digital signature?
I am doing a project related to digital signature and I don't know much about encryption and decryption. On the sender side, I use SHA256 to hash the data and I want to use AES to encrypt to create the signature. On the receiver side, use AES to decrypt the signature, hash the original file and compare the results. Is this possible?
So can I use AES to encrypt and decrypt in the digital signature algorithm?. And, If you have any documents can you send them to me. Thank you very much

Terminology note: what you are describing would not be termed a 'digital signature' (which has two different keys; one to generate the signature and another one to verify).  Instead, what you have might be a Message Authentication Code (MAC).  There are a number of standard Message Authentication Codes out there...

Look at the CBC-MAC, and be careful on the use...

Hi @poncho, i see if i want to do project digital signature I should use RSA for encoding and decoding because it's have 2 different key. But i don't know how to using it, can you give me some tip or manual. Thanks

To decide whether to use a signature or a MAC (or something else entirely), you need to define what security properties you need?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  What do you want to make easy (e.g. generating a signature) and what you want to make infeasible (e.g. faking a signature without a key).
